# Black line appearing at bottom of UIWebView. How to remove?

Tags: html, ios, css, uiwebview

I am rendering some html in a webview that is embedded in a table cell.  For some reason there is a black line at the bottom of the webview.  I tried setting the background color of the webview and its scrollview to white but this did not change anything.  Has anyone seen this before?[image: UIWebView with black line at bottom]

Here is the HTML that is being rendered:

```
<html>
<head>

    <style type="text/css">
a {text-decoration:none;background-color:white;}
    </style>

    <title></title>
</head>

<body style="margin:0;padding:0;background-color:white;">
    <a href="http://body/" style=
    "font-family:HelveticaNeue-Light;font-size:20.000000;color:black;-webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);">
    Portland Blazers vs Golden State Warriors | FULL Highlights | January 26 ,
    2014 | NBA 2013-14 Season</a><span style=
    "font-family:HelveticaNeue;font-size:12.000000;color:rgb(102,102,102);white-space:nowrap;"><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2TfldZ4w57E&amp;feature=youtube_gdata_player"
    style=
    "font-family:HelveticaNeue;font-size:12;color:rgb(102,102,102);-webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);"><img height="12"
    src="file:link@2x.png" width="20">www.youtube.com</a></span>
</body>
</html>
```

This is on iOS7.

**UPDATE:** I'm still not sure what is causing the black line to appear but I managed to get rid of it by changing how I setup my layout constraints.  Before I was setting constraints for the spacing around the views and letting the layout system figure out the size that the view should be.  I changed it to explicitly set a height constraint of the webview when the webview finishes loading its content.  This seems to have fixed the issue but I still do not understand where the black line was coming from.

Comment: Is the CSS in the head section all css you have (except the inline-css)?

Comment: Correct.  I am dynamically creating that HTML string from my model data and loading it into the webview with: [webview loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];

Comment: I tried your code, and didn't get any black border in bottom

Answer (score 184, accepted):

I had same **issue** and **solution** is given below :

1. Set `UIWebView's` `opaque` to `NO`
2. Set `UIWebView's` `backgroundcolor` to `clear` `color`.

**Note : Both things provided above are necessary.**

---

**Other solutions while using above one**

```
webView.scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

**OR**

The meta to go in the head tag of HTML

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Comment: It started to appear with iOS 8 SDK, as well as issue with incorrect size with -sizeThatFits: method.    
Your method works. Thank you.

Comment: Was able to get rid of the black line with `opaque` set to `NO` and `backgroundColor` set to [UIColor whiteColor]` (and if I comment out the `backgroundColor`line I also don't see the black line)

Comment: At first place, why this black line comes, it is a `UIWebView` issue?

Comment: In my case, `UIWebView` already has white background color. Just setting its `opaque` to `NO` makes it works.

Answer (score 0):

As **Phu Nguyen** told in comments the solution is to set `opaque` property of `webView` to `NO`.

```
webView.opaque = NO;
```