# UITableViewCell With UIWebView Dynamic Height

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, uiwebview

I have a table view with cells that have a webView in them, I want the height of the cell to match the height of the webView.

This is the code I use:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("newsCell") as! NewsTableViewCell

    cell.webView.loadHTMLString("test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test", baseURL: nil)
    cell.webView.delegate = self

    var webFrame = cell.webView.frame
    var cellFrame = cell.frame
    cell.frame = CGRectMake(cellFrame.origin.x, cellFrame.origin.y, cellFrame.width, webFrame.height + 20)
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

    return cell
}

func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
    println("finished loading")
    var frame = webView.frame
    frame.size.height = 1
    webView.frame = frame

    var fittingSize = webView.sizeThatFits(CGSizeZero)
    frame.size = fittingSize
    webView.frame = frame

    var height: CGFloat = frame.height
    println(height)

    webView.frame = CGRectMake(frame.origin.x, frame.origin.x, frame.size.width, frame.size.height)

    newsTable.beginUpdates()
    newsTable.endUpdates()
}
```

And this is the result: https://postimg.cc/image/8qew1lqjj/

The webView is the correct height but the cell isn't, How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Great question! Thanks!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

TableView will resize cells itself, you just need implement `tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat` delegate method.

Yes, you don't know the height of WebView initially, but you can calculate it and then ask TableView to reload cell. Something like this:

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController, UIWebViewDelegate
{
    var content : [String] = ["test1<br>test1<br>test1<br>test1<br>test1<br>test1", "test22<br>test22<br>test22<br>test22<br>test22<br>test22"]
    var contentHeights : [CGFloat] = [0.0, 0.0]

    // ...

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("newsCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! NewsTableViewCell
        let htmlString = content[indexPath.row]
        let htmlHeight = contentHeights[indexPath.row]

        cell.webView.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.webView.delegate = self
        cell.webView.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: nil)
        cell.webView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, htmlHeight)

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat
    {
        return contentHeights[indexPath.row]
    }

    func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView)
    {
        if (contentHeights[webView.tag] != 0.0)
        {
            // we already know height, no need to reload cell
            return
        }

        contentHeights[webView.tag] = webView.scrollView.contentSize.height
        tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: webView.tag, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: For some reason the table shows up like this: http://postimg.org/image/wp43uf291, do you know why?

Comment: @OmerN, do you mean black lines? I think it's the same problem as in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21420137/683917).

Comment: This works but has one problem, the loadHTMLString call may contain web content request, if will double the traffic and may drag the app slow if the web call is slow.

Comment: I sill havent worked out.Its still inside cell with scrolling enabled.Any help?

Comment: @ifau,if you don't mind,can you provide with example?Thanks...I really need help with that too.

Comment: @6245Htarwara did you figure out a solution for this ?

Comment: Yes,but not fully worked if u set the constraints like that on web view : http://puu.sh/pPD2Q/fdf4fcbe8d.png. @ifau answer only work if we set constraints like that.Still can't figure out how to resize web view with limited constraints.But,I got another way to solve this basic html case.Here : https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel . Try that,it worked like a charm.

Comment: I am reloading the table after getting data from server. So  contentHeights list some how contains same value not 0. So each cell height fix to the first cell height . So i changed the condition in  webViewDidFinishLoad method - ---  if (contentHeights[webView.tag] == webView.scrollView.contentSize.height)
        {
            // we already know height, no need to reload cell
            return
        }

Comment: @ifau webView.scrollView.contentSize.height is not giving size equal to content height

Comment: This worked for me with 1 caveat. I had created the cell in IB and I had to set it's height to be quite small (essentially smaller than a line of text) otherwise it wouldn't resize the cell.

Comment: When I tried this method, my web view frame would never be more than 20px for some reason. I looked in the view debugger and it turned out that one of the subviews of the web view's scroll view (a UIWebBrowserView, an internal Apple class) was the correct size but that the web view was clipping  it. I set my contentHeight to webView.scrollView.subviews.first?.frame.height and voila! It worked like a charm. (Warning: UIWebBrowserView is an undocumented API, but as we're not directly referencing it, we should be fine.)

Comment: Not the best but I am going to use it ;)

Answer (score 7):

**Swift 4**

*ifau's* Answer modified for Swift 4, using `UITableView` instead of `UITableViewController`.

In storyboard, take a `UITableView`. Add 1 prototype cell to it. Keep the reuseIdentifier of the cell to "`cell`". Drag a `webView` into the cell and set leading, trailing, top and bottom constraints to 0. Set the cell class to `TableViewCell`

**TableViewCell.swift**

Connect webView outlet to storyboard:

```
import UIKit

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

**ViewController.swift**

Connect the tableView outlet to the storyboard:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UIWebViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var content : [String] = ["test1<br>test1<br>test1", "test22<br>test22<br>test22<br>test22<br>test22<br>test22"]

    var contentHeights : [CGFloat] = [0.0, 0.0]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        return content.count
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
        let cell : TableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! TableViewCell

        let htmlString = content[indexPath.row]
        let htmlHeight = contentHeights[indexPath.row]

        cell.webView.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.webView.delegate = self
        cell.webView.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: nil)
        cell.webView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: cell.frame.size.width, height: htmlHeight)

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if contentHeights[indexPath.row] != 0 {
            return contentHeights[indexPath.row]
        }
    }

    public func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView){
        if (contentHeights[webView.tag] != 0.0)
        {
            // we already know height, no need to reload cell
            return
        }

        contentHeights[webView.tag] = webView.scrollView.contentSize.height
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: webView.tag, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
    }
}
```

Comment: Added `contentHeights[indexPath.row] != 0` prevents autoLayout break

Comment: Oh my god, I spent 150 stack overflow point to get this solution, But didn't get a perfect solution. This makes my day. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4):

It's work for me, easy Way to load Html String on WebView with dynamic.

First take textView in TableViewCell with scroll disable and then take WebView, Apply Zero constraint on all 4 Side with ContentView. Now give same height constraint to both textview and WebView.Now give same text to both view as shown below code.

For Clean UI Hide textView From XIB or storyBoard.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 100
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableviewcell") as! tableviewcell
    let theString : String = "</p><img src='https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/655066410087940096/QSUlrrlm.png' width=100 height=100 /><h2>Subheader</h2>"

    let theAttributedString = try! NSAttributedString(data: theString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!,options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType],  documentAttributes: nil)

    cell.textview.attributedText =  theAttributedString

    cell.webview.loadHTMLString(theString, baseURL: nil)

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Even need to have a hidden textview but this method works for me too.

Comment: Thank you, yes, you need to hide textView. I added that on answer

Comment: I think this will not work if your html contains any img or styling as in textview every tag will be consider as text like: <img>,So height will also change .

Comment: @Sibasish can you please come with example code. so i can understand.

Comment: It works for most of the time, but occasionally I got this crash: WebKitLegacy  0x19590f7e0 -[_WebSafeForwarder forwardInvocation:] + 132. I'm not sure that it caused by NSAttributedString(data:) or not.

Answer (score 1):

After calculating the height of webview **Use DispatchQueue** for reloading the tableViewcell height `DispatchQueue.main.async`.It avoids abnormal empty spaces and crash while reloading webview frame

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView)
{
    var frame : CGRect = webVwModule.frame;
    frame.size.height = 1;
    self.webVwModule.frame.size = webVwModule.sizeThatFits(.zero)
    frame.size = self.webVwModule.frame.size;
    webView.frame = frame;
    webViewContentHeight = self.webVwModule.frame.size.height;
    isWebViewLoaded = true

    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
       self.tableView.beginUpdates()
        self.tableView.endUpdates()
    })
    }

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        return webViewContentHeight!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var heightOfWebview=0    

func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ aWebView: UIWebView)
{
    var frame: CGRect = aWebView.frame
    frame.size.height = 1
    aWebView.frame = frame
    let fittingSize = aWebView.sizeThatFits(CGSize.zero)
    frame.size = fittingSize
    aWebView.frame = frame
    heightOfWebview = Int(fittingSize.height)
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()
    print("Calling webViewDidFinishLoad. Cell size value: \(heightOfWebview)")

}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
    return CGFloat(220+heightOfWebview) /// 220 is my static value
}
```

Comment: It does n't resize the webView according to it's content.

Answer (score 0):

The best way worked for me.

```
var heightOfWebview: CGFloat = 0    

func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ aWebView: UIWebView)
{
    var frame: CGRect = aWebView.frame
    frame.size.height = 1
    aWebView.frame = frame
    let fittingSize = aWebView.sizeThatFits(CGSize.zero)
    frame.size = fittingSize
    aWebView.frame = frame
    heightOfWebview = Int(fittingSize.height)
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()
    print("Calling webViewDidFinishLoad. Cell size value: \(heightOfWebview)")

}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
    return heightOfWebview
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most easy and elegant way is

1. Add height layout constraint for webview
2. Add webview Delegate finished loading then set contentSize height to constant of height layout constraint.
3. Keep instance of tableview or make a delegate - block - closure to main tableview.
4. Call tableview beginupdate endupdate to let tableview know they should validate layout.

```js
class WebViewTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    weak var viewController: ViewController? = nil
    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var heightLayoutConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        webView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://tinhte.vn")!))
        webView.delegate = self
        webView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
extension WebViewTableViewCell: UIWebViewDelegate {
    func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
        heightLayoutConstraint.constant = webView.scrollView.contentSize.height
        viewController?.tableView.beginUpdates()
        viewController?.tableView.endUpdates()
    }
}
```

Comment: This will not work for dynamic request. Here you muss set request statically in `awakeFromNib`. If you set request later, for example in `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`, the line `tableView.beginUpdates() and ..,` will create loop

Answer (score 0):

I have one more solution that you should consider. Make a height constraint and link it to your `UITableViewCell` class. Then implement the delegate method `func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView)`, and when it is called set the height constraint to be equal to `webView.scrollView.contentSize.height`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
class WebViewTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    weak var viewController: ViewController? = nil
    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var heightLayoutConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        webView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://tinhte.vn")!))
        webView.delegate = self
        webView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
extension WebViewTableViewCell: UIWebViewDelegate {
    func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
        heightLayoutConstraint.constant = webView.scrollView.contentSize.height
        viewController?.tableView.beginUpdates()
        viewController?.tableView.endUpdates()
    }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Implement the UITableview delegate 
heightforrowatindexpath to return the webview frame height.

Comment: But i only get the webView height after the webViewDidFinishLoad function