# swift UIWebView in UITableView: change webview height dynamically

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiwebview

In my tableview cells, there are webviews that have different contents . I am new in ios. according to objective-c answers. 
I call in function "cellForRowAtIndexPath"

```
cell.contentWeb.loadHTMLString(entries[indexPath.row].title, baseURL: nil)
```

and I try

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
    var frame: CGRect = webView.frame
    frame.size.height = 1
    webView.frame = frame
    var fittingSize: CGSize = webView.sizeThatFits(CGSizeZero)
    frame.size = fittingSize
    webView.frame = frame
     webViewHeight = fittingSize.height
    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    self.tableView.endUpdates()
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> CGFloat {
    if(indexPath.section == 0){
        if(indexPath.row == 0){
            return self.webViewHeight + 10
        }
    }
    return 80
}
```

these functions. but I fail to change height of the cells according to webview. Question is how can I manage to change size of the cells to fit webview height.

Comment: you need to force table view to reload row containing your webview as it finishes loading its content. -                 `tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)`

Comment: Yesterday I answered a [very similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32548771/683917), look, I think it may be helpful to you.

Comment: thanks @ifau now my cells resize according to height. However, content of the html is in fixed sized box. they dont fit new sized cell.

Comment: @sof98789, setup your cell layout with autolayout constraint, if you haven't done it yet. For example, i added zero space to all sides and webview fills cell ([screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/o9jDV.png)).

Comment: @ifau, I also tried this but I get error that says _Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want_ . and also cells are again fixed sizes. I give id to all constraints and I guess the problem is bottom constraint.

Comment: @sof98789, I can try find your problem, if you show me cell layout with all constraints that it has. Full error message also can be helpful, because it contains information about the conflict constraints.

Comment: @ifau, I add constraints by unchecking _constrain to margins_ and it solves the problem. Thanks for ur help