# UITableViewCell with UIWebview that adjusts height to content size

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiwebview

So I am pulling an HTML string down from an API and I am trying to load it into a UIWebView that is in a UITableViewCell and the content scrolls in the cell. I need to have the webview's height adjust to the size of the content and then adjust the cell accordingly. I found a post here in swift: 
[UITableViewCell With UIWebView Dynamic Height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32548771/uitableviewcell-with-uiwebview-dynamic-height?newreg=1430d857dd18473a8cf941bbb807e3eb)
And I tried doing the same thing but I am having some trouble because I am using a NSMutableArray to store a NSNumber with float and then trying to load it in but cellForRowAtIndexPath and heightForRowAtIndexPath both execute before the webview delegate method gets called so I will get an index out of bounds error.

So far I have this:

```
@interface FGCThreadDetailTableViewController ()

@property (copy, nonatomic) NSArray<FGCThreadModel*>* threads;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSMutableArray* contentHeights;

@end

@implementation FGCThreadDetailTableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.tableView registerClass:[FGCThreadDetailCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"threadDetailCell"];
    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100;
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
    [SVProgressHUD show];
    [[FGCThread postsByThreadID:_threadID] subscribeNext:^(id x) {
        _threads = x;
        [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }];
    _contentHeights = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return _threads.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    FGCThreadDetailCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"threadDetailCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    FGCThreadModel* thread = _threads[indexPath.row];
    cell.webView.delegate = self;
    CGFloat htmlHeight;
    htmlHeight = [_contentHeights[indexPath.row] floatValue];
    cell.webView.tag = indexPath.row;
    [cell.webView loadHTMLString:thread.postBodyHTMLString baseURL:nil];
    cell.webView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, htmlHeight);
    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return [_contentHeights[indexPath.row] floatValue];
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    if (_contentHeights[webView.tag]) {
        return;
    }
    _contentHeights[webView.tag] = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:[[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.offsetHeight;"] floatValue]];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

@end
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you add some piece of code to help you?

Comment: @ReinierMelian added. Thanks!

Comment: I wonder if you could use dynamic cell height, and use an auto layout constraint to size the cell. In your `webViewDidFinishLoad` you could update the `constant` on the height constraint for the appropriate cell. Might be easier than storing the heights.

Comment: @DylanS Im not sure i get what you mean... Idk how I could do that. I am using a dynamic cell height but I cant do much in webview did finish loading because it will cause a loop if I put reload data in there after the height has been updated.

Comment: You don't want to `reloadData` in that method. With dynamic cell height, you can adjust the cell height anytime and the table will update. Can you add an auto layout constraint to the cell so that its height has to equal the web view height? Then you can update the web view's height in `webViewDidFinishLoad`. You also will need to remove your implementation of `heightForRowAtIndexPath` so that the table view will use the cell's height.

Comment: @DylanS is there any way you could post a code example?

Comment: @DylanS because i believe I have already tried that. I have a custom cell that constrains the webview to the super views of the cell's contentview and then i set the webviews frame on `webViewDidFinishLoading` and the table should auto update correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The auto layout approach might be tricky. An easier approach is to just set the frame of the corresponding cell in `webViewDidFinishLoad`. You can use `cellForRowAtIndexPath` on the table view to get the displayed cell (it won't try to get the cell from the `UITableViewDataSource` if it's already displayed because it'll be cached).

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    if (_contentHeights[webView.tag]) {
        return;
    }
    float height = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:[[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.offsetHeight;"] floatValue]];

    NSIndexPath* indexOfCell = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:webView.tag inSection:0];
    UITableViewCell* cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexOfCell];
    cell.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, height);
}
```

Comment: So essentially this is what I was doing to start with... but the problem is when it tries to evaluate `_contentHeights[webView.tag]` its going to throw an exception because there will be no 1st or 2nd element in the array which was my original problem.

Comment: @TylerRister Removed the `_contentsHeight` since it shouldn't exist. You can't use the `_contentsHeight` in `heightForRowAtIndexPath` because it isn't possible to have the heights so just use automatic cell height.