# Resizing UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift3, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am using UICollectionView to show records, for a record I have created an xib file looking like below

[image]

1 . Title webview contains post title (if available)
2 . Imageview contains post image (if available)
3 .Text webview contains post text(if available)

data is coming from remote server.
I have  created a separate UIcollectionViewCell class to set data.

I want my UIcollectionViewCell resized according to cell data. previously I was Overriding

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

return size
}
```

to get it done, but it is not perfect for me. How I can resize the cell According to the sizes of

1 . Title html

2 . Image

3 . Text html

Now what I am trying to do is

in my UIcollectionViewCell class

```
    if text != nil {
    postTextWebView.delegate = self            
postTextWebView.loadHTMLString(text!, baseURL: bundleURL as URL)
            }
            else{
                postTextWebView.loadHTMLString("", baseURL: nil)
                postTextHeightConstraint.constant = 0
            }
```

this class overrides
webViewDidFinishLoad() function of UIWebViewDelegate

```
 func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
       var frame : CGRect = webView.frame;
        frame.size.height = 1;
        webView.frame = frame;
        let fittingSize : CGSize = webView.sizeThatFits(.zero)
        frame.size = fittingSize;
        webView.frame = frame;
       
        
        if let sizeCalculator = self.dynamicSizeCalculator {
            sizeCalculator.calculateVariableSize(tag: postTextWebView.tag, variableSize: fittingSize.height, indexPath: IndexPath.init(row: postTextWebView.tag, section: 0))
        }
    }

protocol DynamicSizeCalculator:class{
    func calculateVariableSize(tag:Int,variableSize:CGFloat,indexPath:IndexPath)
}
```

In my View controller class

```
var variableHeights:[CGFloat]? = []
    var isFirstTimeLoaded : Bool = false
```

when data is fetched from server Bool value becomes true

```
 override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
    }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
     let cell:Cell
      cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "softBoardPostCell", for: indexPath) as! Cell
                cell.postTextWebView.tag = indexPath.row
                    cell.dynamicSizeCalculator = self
                    cell.drawCell(posts[indexPath.row])
                    cell.sbActionChosenListner=self
                    return cell
           
            }
            
            
            func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
                
                return posts.count
            }


 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
//        var cellHeight:CGFloat = 20 + 19.5 + 9.5+14.5+8+16+9+16+10+34+12+14.5+8.5+32+20+12;
        if isFirstTimeLoaded{
            variableHeights?.insert(0.0, at: indexPath.item)
        }
        var cellHeight : CGFloat = 20+48+11+14+10+14.5+14.5+11.5+32+13
        if let userName = posts[indexPath.item].user_name{
            let userNameRect = NSString(string:userName).boundingRect(with: CGSize(width:view.frame.width,height:200), options: NSStringDrawingOptions.usesFontLeading.union(NSStringDrawingOptions.usesLineFragmentOrigin), attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)], context: nil)
            cellHeight = cellHeight + userNameRect.height
        }
        if let postTitle = posts[indexPath.item].post_text_title?.html2String{
             let titleRect = NSString(string:postTitle).boundingRect(with: CGSize(width:view.frame.width,height:1000), options: NSStringDrawingOptions.usesFontLeading.union(NSStringDrawingOptions.usesLineFragmentOrigin), attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)], context: nil)
            cellHeight = cellHeight+titleRect.height 
        }

  
        if  posts[indexPath.item].post_text != nil{
cellHeight = cellHeight+(variableHeights?[indexPath.row])!
            
        }

        
        if  posts[indexPath.item].post_img_url != nil{
         
            
            let contentType = posts[indexPath.item].post_content_type!
            switch contentType {
            case "EXTERNAL_LINK":
                
                fallthrough
                case "EXTERNAL_VIDEO":
                cellHeight = cellHeight+300
                break
            default:
                let postImageUrl=posts[indexPath.item].post_img_url!
                let imageUrl = URL(string: postImageUrl)
                
                do{
                    let imageData = try Data(contentsOf: imageUrl!)
                    let image = UIImage(data: imageData)
                    if image != nil{
                        cellHeight = cellHeight + image!.size.height
                    }
                }
                catch let error {
                    print("ERROR : \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
            }
           
            
            
            }

        
        return CGSize(width:view.frame.width,height:cellHeight)
    }



 func calculateVariableSize(tag:Int,variableSize:CGFloat,indexPath:IndexPath){
        isFirstTimeLoaded = false
         print("variable size \(String(describing: variableHeights?.count))")
        if variableHeights?[tag] == 0.0{
            variableHeights?[tag]=variableSize
            //collectionView.reloadSections(IndexSet.init())
            collectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])
        }
```

I pass delegate to resize the cell according to web view content, but after receiving delegate
It look like (cells overlap each other)

[image]

Any help here?

Comment: use stack view it is usefull when you hide image or webview

Answer (score 1):

> Remove the Bottom Contraint for text html lable Give(Leading, Trailing,top and fix height
>   and select heightContraint  make height Contraint >=) U Should
>   calculate the height of the string for Text Html

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

//Calculate the height of the string text  
return size + TextHtmlHeight
}
```

> then cell will Increase according to the text height

Comment: previously I was calculating the size by unwrapping the string from html, but I leaves space at the bottom@Ramesh

Comment: this is not label, it is webview

Comment: I get html, It may be external link, video or any html document @Ramesh

Comment: @Mansuu.... if you want to show full content in the webview and increase cell height according to content  You need to increase content size of webView and add that height to the size of the cell Height. u can have alook at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32548771/uitableviewcell-with-uiwebview-dynamic-height

Comment: I tried using that, but I use separate controller class and UICollectionViewCell class. I used to make it by sending delegate from UICollectionViewCell to controller class, but it takes very long to send the delegate and when delegate received and That specific cell reloaded, Cells overlap each other @Ramesh

Comment: @Mansuu.... if u set the methods in collectionview cell it doesnt matter reload collectionview properly when you get response from server .and make sure all colllectionview delegates are set properly. overlapping? one cell with other cell ? or content inside cell is mess ? how ?

Comment: i have edited the question , It can make you understand better, please have a look @Ramesh

Comment: No Ramesh not yet. @Ramesh

Comment: @Mansuu....             collectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath]) instead of this reload collectionView   collectionView.reloadData() when u get webviewdata

Comment: but will it resize all items according to new size.@Ramesh

Comment: @Mansuu....    But u didnt add the Webview Content height based on the result of webview content  to cell height  here right?     return CGSize(width:view.frame.width,height:cellHeight)

Comment: I am passing the size of the webview through delegate and maintain an array. look closely in sizeforItemAt callback, please @Ramesh