# Setting heightForRow with UILabel & UIWebView in UITableview swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiwebview

I just looking for dynamic height of `UIWebView` with `UILabel` on `UITableViewCell`.

[This is great example for UIWebView in UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47386748/7576100)

But i am using `UILabel` along with `UIWebView` in `UITableViewCell`.

I have set `numberOfLines` to `0`. & taken greater equal height constraint for `UILabel` & setting the constant according to `UILabel` height.

```
extension UILabel {   
    func getNoOfLines() ->Int{
        let textSize = CGSize(width: self.frame.size.width, height: CGFloat(Float.infinity))
        let rHeight = lroundf(Float(self.sizeThatFits(textSize).height))
        let charSize = lroundf(Float(self.font.lineHeight))
        return rHeight/charSize
    }
}

let lineCount = cell.questionLabel.getNoOfLines()
let labelLineHeight =  (cell.questionLabel.font.lineHeight * CGFloat(lineCount))
print("Line height is ",labelLineHeight)
```

& setting the height constraint on `heightForRowAt` which is addition of WebView Height + labelLineHeight.

Problem is `UILabel` get trunk even after setting height constraint. Yes i also used `layoutIfNeeded()`.

I just looking for dynamic height of `UIWebView` with `UILabel` on `UITableViewCell`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set any height for UILabel you have to just set bottom space to and top space and set [numberOfLines](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilabel/1620539-numberoflines) to 0 and also width of UILabel. For Reference, please see these two pictures below:
[image: example 1]

[image: example 2]

Hope this will help.